# How to find a host's FQDN from its IP address in Python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a python script in which I have an IP address from which I need to find the associated host's FQDN.

I know there are socket.getfqdn() and socket.gethostbyaddr() calls but they are giving only the hostname in this case and not the FQDN.

However, if I'm running 'host ' or 'nslookup ' on my local linux pc it shows me the FQDN of that host.

Please help me if there is any way to achieve it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Use [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html).

Examples for reverse lookup include things like this:

```
>>> from dns import resolver,reversename
>>> addr=reversename.from_address("74.125.228.97")
>>> str(resolver.query(addr,"PTR")[0])
'iad23s08-in-f1.1e100.net.'
>>>
```